# Code refactoring with polymorphism

Tags: java, refactoring, polymorphism

There is Base class and some classes derived from it Child1, Child2, Child3 etc.
Given the code:

```
    Base object;
    String data = ...;

    switch(data) {
        case "Child1" :
            object = new Child1();
            break;
        case "Child2" :
            object = new Child2();
            break;
        case "Child3" :
            object = new Child3():
            break;
        default:
            object = null;
            break;
    }
```

Any idea how to refactor it, if it's possible?

Comment: Use an `enum`? Use reflection? We don't know what you want to do therefore any advice provided will be generic.

Comment: Clue: Child 1, 2, and 3 are all 'Child'. So you do not need three classes. What if there are 1 million 'Child'?

Comment: @SajalDutta I suppose you could be right, the OP could be confusing classes with instances...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Very much possible. In that case, the Child object should be created with some parameters that identifies in his case which 'Child'.

Comment: I want to set instance of Base class new object depending on what value String parameter holds. Suppose, String data can hold only values that match with the names of derived classes

Comment: What you have could probably be described as ["parameterized Factory"](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) which is not bad per se. Link also has some improvement ideas (i.e. dynamically register parameter <> subclass pairs), in case that is what you are trying to achieve in that code...

Answer (score 2):

Try (untested):

```
public enum BaseType{
    CHILD_1("Child1"){
      @Override
      public Base createBase(){
          return new Child1();
      }
    },
    CHILD_2("Child2"){
      @Override
      public Base createBase(){
          return new Child2();
      }
    },
    CHILD_3("Child3"){
      @Override
      public Base createBase(){
          return new Child3();
      }
    };
    private static final Map<String, BaseType> TYPES = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for(BaseType type : values()){
            TYPES.put(type.name, type);
        }
    }

    private final String name;

    protected BaseType(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract Base createBase();

    public static BaseType getBaseType(String name){
        return TYPES.get(name);
    }

}



Base base = null;
String data = ...;
BaseType baseType = BaseType.getBaseType(data);
if (baseType != null){
   base = baseType.createBase();
}
```

Comment: Nice one. And the OOP way, as each future enum that might get added is forced to implement the abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your follow-up comment it sounds like this is what you are trying to do:

```
    Base object;
    String data = ...;

    object = (Base)Class.forName(data).newInstance();
```

Comment: Depending on data you might also have to prepend some package.